# arduino mega draw more current from pins

Tags: arduino

I have the Arduino Mega,
i need more than the `40mA` supplied by the pins to power up my dc-motors,
Is there a way to increase those `40mA` to more like `100mA` or so?

thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can instead of connecting the dc motor with 1 pin to each terminal (+ve, -ve)
you can connect 2 or more (to add-up the current)

assuming a pin gives `40mA` and you need `100mA`, then you can connect each terminal from the dc-motor to 3 pins from the arduino providing `120mA`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an SO question since it doesn't have anything to do with programming ... but anyway: You don't want to be driving a motor directly from an Arduino. Aside from the lack of adequate power, the motor will also generate spikes and electronic noise which will affect the Ardunio.

There are loads of tutorials on the web here's [one](http://bildr.org/2011/03/high-power-control-with-arduino-and-tip120/). If you want to be able to reverse direction then you would use what is called an [H-Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge).